# How to install Gitlab on an offline network?

Tags: gitlab, offline

See title. I have a network not connected to the internet that I would like to host a gitlab server on.

edit: part of my problem seems to be with the Chef client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but don't you just download the install package from a machine that is on the Internet, copy it to a media that you can use to copy it to a machine on the isolated network, and then install?

Edit: I see your issue may be the use of git cloning to install.  You might find an rpm or deb packaged version, which are listed in "alernative installation methods" by gitlab.

Comment: I've installed the deb but can't figure out why it's not working. I have other servers running on this machine and just wanted to make sure I didn't skip a step because git lab gave me no change to set default options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using docker images. 
Download the docker binaries here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/

and also the docker image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/

By this you can install a GitLab offline. But that only requires a download which can be done from other place.